# Perl: Searching Patterns which occur in a certain time difference

Tags: perl, pattern-matching, timedelta

First my problem: I have a document in which I want to search for two patterns. In every line, there is a time stamp. So there's a time in the line with the pattern, too.

Now I want to get only those two patterns, which occur in a certain time difference or where the time difference is higher than my typed in time (which i want to determine). Like:

```
19:03 Pattern1 
19:04 Pattern2
20:04 Pattern1
20:10 Pattern2

time difference: 4 sec
```

I calculated the absolute time and differences. The pattern matching is no problem.
But my problem is to give out the line of all the lines/patterns which have a time difference greater than e.g. 4 sec.

Comment: Can we see some of your code so we can help?

Comment: Give the code that you have working so far - it will make suggestions easier.

Comment: Pattern1 and Pattern2 always happen in pairs?  Do they ever overlap (Pattern1, Pattern1, Pattern2, Pattern2)?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually ask a question! Maybe you want the matched lines?

```
my ($pat1_time, $pat1_line); 
while (<>) {
   my $time = ...;
   if (/pat1/) {
      $pat1_line = $_;
      $pat1_time = $time;
   }
   if (/pat2/) {
      if ($time - $pat1_time > 4) {
         print($pat1_line);
         print($_);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: time doesn't appear to be an integer

Comment: @ysth, He said he knows how to convert it to an absolute time, which I took to mean epoch time. Shrug. If there's a problem, the OP will let me know.